# Counting bits and printing result LC3 Assembly

Tags: assembly, output, bit-shift, bit, lc3

I'm trying to write a simple program that takes a 16-bit integer from Data1, counts how many bits are 1-bits, and then prints the result to the screen. I'm quite certain my code should do the trick, but for some reason the output I get is a little box symbol, instead of the actual integer value. Does anyone know why I'm getting this output and how I can change it?? This is the code I have:

```
    .orig x3000 ;start at address x3000
LD R1, Data1    ;load R1 with Data1
AND R2, R2, #0  ;clear R2
ADD R2, R2, #1  ;set R2 to 1
    ;R2 will be compared with the data
    ;value to see if the bit is 1
AND R3, R3, #0  ;clear R3
    ;R3 will be used as the counter
AND R4, R4, #0  ;R4 will hold the answer

while
    ADD R3, R3, #1  ;add 1 to the counter
    AND R0, R0, #0
    AND R0, R1, R2  ;compare R1 and R2
    brp yes ;if the bit is 1, goto yes
no
    ADD R2, R2, R2  ;shift bits left
    br check    ;skip over yes
yes
    ADD R4, R4, #1  ;increase the counter
    br no   ;continue
check
    AND R0, R0, #0
    ADD R0, R3, #-16    ;if counter is still under 16
    brn while
endwhile
    LEA R0, msg ;load message
    PUTS    ;print message
AND R0, R0, #0
ADD R0, R4, #0  ;put R4 (answer) in R0
OUT ;print it to screen

HALT
Data1   .FILL x0002 ;this variable changes
msg .STRINGZ "\nNumber of non-zero bits: "

.end
```

The output I should get is:

```
Number of non-zero bits: 1
```

(Since the value being checked is 2, and there is 1 1-bit in 2)
But the output I DO get is:

```
Number of non-zero bits: ☐
```

Any help or advice would be very much appreciated!! I'm still very new to LC3 assembly...

Comment: there are many much faster ways to count bits [here](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetNaive)

Comment: I'm sure there are, but I'm not looking for efficiency here. I need to do it in LC3 assembly since it is an assignment, and I'm just trying to figure out why the way I have implemented it doesn't work. But thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're forgetting that OUT prints the character that the ASCII value points to. You would need to increase your answer by 48. You'll then run into problems when it comes to numbers of bits over 9, so you'd need to do some checking there.

Hope that helps!